# How to transfer object dataframe in sklearn.ensemble methods

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, scikit-learn

As usual: doing first steps in Data Science.
Trying to build Extra Trees REgressor model from the data frame with lists.
The features DataFrame `X` is 47724 rows × 27 columns, each cell contains a list with 4 numbers, for example [7.69, 7.68, 7.66, 7.74].
The target Y is a series of floats.
After transferring all data to regressor model, there is a mistake: *setting an array element with a sequence*.
How to fix it?

Have tried to use advices from [SKLearn ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56980042/sklearn-valueerror-setting-an-array-element-with-a-sequence)
and to use `np.array` but it gives another error: `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist'`. A slight difference here is that the list with the data at the beginning whether I have data frame, or I don't see the right way to use it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A Series, a column of your frame, has a `.to_list` method.  The whole frames does not.  `df.to_numpy()` should produce an object dtype array.  `np.array(df.to_numpy().tolist())` might work, producing a (47724, 27, 3) shape array.